# How can I handle Excel Protocol popup in protractor?

Tags: protractor, popup, alert

After clicking on Excel document name in application, a Excel protocol popup appears. How can I handle that popup or how can i get the text of that popup.

Note: I tried using alert in protractor but it's not working.

Comment: could you at least share with us what have you already tried? Some code? is it a browser pop-up? if not how does that element look on the html?

Comment: I tried this code from my side :browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent(), 1000); 

  const alertDialog = browser.switchTo().alert();
  expect(alertDialog.getText()).toEqual('Hello');
  alertDialog.accept();

Comment: And yes it's a browser popup.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+protocol+popup+in+chrome&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjdxO3otfLiAhU3AbcAHcHPAZ8Q2-cCegQIABAC&oq=excel+protocol+popup+in+chrome&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-img.3...35759.38236..40034...1.0..0.188.1198.0j9......0....1.........33i10.Fgs6K-_al9Q&ei=8oYIXd2DBbeC3LUPwZ-H-Ak&bih=648&biw=360&client=ms-android-oppo&prmd=vin#imgrc=zqmuK0xyVvl7CM